# Can you use Twilio Test Credentials in the API Explorer

Tags: twilio

Is it possible to use the Twilio supplied Test Credential in their API Explorer?

I tried and get an error returned. I'm new to using the API Explorer and Test Credentials so maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

You'd have to be able to specify both the Account Sid and AuthToken, and I don't believe the API Explorer lets you set the AuthToken.

I'm curious what your looking to achieve by using test credentials with the API explorer.